# Why asynchronous invocation does not work with callback pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have followed the demonstrations of asynchronous invocations patterns in this Microsoft document: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315582

In Sample 5, there is an example code that demonstrates the the **callback pattern**, but it does not work. This is the example code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Recipe.Ch04
{
    public class AsyncDemo
    {
        string LongRunningMethod (int iCallTime, out int iExecThread)
        {
            Thread.Sleep (iCallTime) ;
            iExecThread = AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId ();
            return "MyCallTime was " + iCallTime.ToString() ;
        }

        delegate string MethodDelegate(int iCallTime, out int iExecThread)  ;

        public void DemoCallback()
        {
            MethodDelegate dlgt = new MethodDelegate (this.LongRunningMethod) ;
            string s ;
            int iExecThread;

            // Create the callback delegate.
            AsyncCallback cb = new AsyncCallback(MyAsyncCallback);

            // Initiate the Asynchronous call passing in the callback delegate
            // and the delegate object used to initiate the call.
            IAsyncResult ar = dlgt.BeginInvoke(3000, out iExecThread, cb, dlgt); 
        }

        public void MyAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            string s ;
            int iExecThread ;

            // Because you passed your original delegate in the asyncState parameter
            // of the Begin call, you can get it back here to complete the call.
            MethodDelegate dlgt = (MethodDelegate) ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the call.
            s = dlgt.EndInvoke (out iExecThread, ar) ;

            Console.WriteLine (string.Format ("The delegate call returned the string: \"{0}\", and the number {1}", s, iExecThread.ToString() ) );
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AsyncDemo ad = new AsyncDemo () ;
            ad.DemoCallback() ;
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this callback pattern implementation? Why it compiles but does not show anything on console screen?

Online compilation and execution: http://ideone.com/V8b2NY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a console application usually stops as soon as the `Main()` method returns. There is nothing that would make it wait for code that executes on a background thread.

The simplest solution (but one that's unusable for production applications) is to add `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of `Main()`. That way, `Main()` won't return until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, so you can make sure the application doesn't exit prematurely.